# Polymer child attached event listener on parent

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0

I want to call public api methods on my child element once its attached to my parent. I tried using parent's attached event but its called before child attached event. Tried wiring event like this, doesn't work.

```
<my-element on-attached="childAttached"></my-element>
```

Is there a polymer solution to it, only solution I can see is raising my own event once child is attached.

```
this.fire('child-attached');
<my-element on-child-attached="childAttached"></my-element>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you call `this.fire('child-attached')` in the child element then the binding should be

```
<my-element on-child-attached="childAttached"></my-element>
```

assuming `childAttached()` is a method on the parent.

Comment: Ofcourse I know that, but my question is. Is that the only way i.e.raise my own event and wire it up. Instead of wiring to polymer default attached event

Comment: There is no `attached` event. `attached` is only a lifecycle callback - calls `attached()` on your component when't it's attached.